# Validate Dropdown list selected value > 0 if asp.net form textbox.text >0

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, jquery-validate, validation, html-select

Code language = VB. ASP.NET 4.0

I have a formview control on my page defaulted to insert mode so when the page loads the only thing you can do is insert a records.  I have a bound dropdownlist that defaults to the value of "none"..This can be classified as leave type.. Then I have next to that a textbox classified as hours..

I want to validate that is someone enters time for the textbox that they must choose a value from the dropdownlist.

once I get this far, I then have to repeat it threee times, So I would like to find a way to also write the control either grouping or referencing multiple controls.

If txtbox1.text > 0 then dropdownlist1.selected value must be >0

I could possibly get close just starting there but I find working in asp with the formview control a bit difficult to actually find the control. I have to use the following statements to work with any controls which is a pain 
     directcast(formview1.findcontrol("textbox1"), textbox).text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it easier:  do something like this:

```
With formview1
    Dim txtbox1Value as string = directcast(.findcontrol("textbox1"),textbox).Text
    Dim dropdownlist1Value as string = directcast(.FindControl("dropdownlist1"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
    if txtbox1Value > "0" Then
       if dropdownlist1Value <= "0" Then
           ' Error
       End If
       If dropdownlist1Value >= "100" Then
           ' Another error
       End If
    End If
    ' etc.
End With
```

The idea:  get all the values you need to test in a convenient form up front, then implement your logic.  This will make your logic simpler because you won't be distracted by the finding-and-casting you have to do.

Actually, you could wrap all that in the ServerValidate event of a CustomValidator.

Comment: Not familiar with the servervalidate event. Let me do some research and get back with you on that. However.. Your with event as mentioned above. Where would you think that would go?

Comment: after reading I see this is based on server side validation. Wouldn't I want this to be client side?  If so or if not. Could you or someone explain why

Comment: Sure.  I only made it server-side because you included the code snippet `directcast(formview1.findcontrol("textbox1"), textbox).text`, which is server-side.

Comment: You can do any of the following: write a client validation script for a CustomValidator control; write a custom validator from scratch, including client code; write your own validation routine in jQuery or a similar framework.

Comment: This is in the right step but now fo0r some reason my textbox's are returning 0's for their values which I initially set.  A whole nother issue.......

Comment: Good luck!  (I should also probably point out that you should back up client-side validation with server-side validation, just in case someone has javascript turned off!)